# Tool for generating POCO/DTO from database (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

What **free** tools can generate simple POCO/DTO classes from MS SQL Server database? With Properties and fields, but **nothing more**.

Comment: What version of the .net framework are you using?

Comment: What data access layer are you using: LINQ to SQL, EF4, EF4+CTP5, ...?

Comment: @Richard: FluentNHibernate (non-debatable choice of preference)

Comment: @bretddog: that info should be in the question and tags.

Comment: @Richard: Imo that info is irrelevant to my clear and precise question.

Comment: @bretddog: I disagree. E.g. including attributes for mapping column names (e.g. where name in db is not a valid C# identifier) depend on DB.

Comment: Asking for tools, software or libraries should be done here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [MyGeneration](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/) - it's a free code generation tool for SQL Server that lets you define templates that will be driven by the database structure.

*You* decide what will come out on the other side.

Comment: Thanks! How come this gets down-voted, and without a comment?  Anyway; Could I ask also what to specify as "provider" for SQLExpress? I connect successfully with other tools with this link: (Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RoboDBTest;Integrated Security=True;) ... But if I (with MyGenerator) put Provider=SQLOLEDB; in front of that, I get connection error: [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException] - No error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).

Comment: @bretddog - I don't know exactly. Look on http://connectionstrings.com and try different options for your version.

Comment: @bretddog I expect this was down voted because is looks like spam -- advert for some web site without any attribution.

Comment: @Richard: It looks nothing like spam. It's a FREE tool. It targets my question 100%. And answer is given by a highly respected member.

Comment: @bretddog: Which is why I have not yet flagged it as spam, but I'm still considering it.

Comment: My Connection string issue noted above (for SQL Express to MyGeneration) was solved like this: "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=windowslogin;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: no matter what I do. I cant seem to get rid of this error. [System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationException] - You must have administrative credentials to perform this task. Contact your system administrator for assistance.

Comment: you know what it means? While installing i did see some failure message in the dos window that opened up.. But the window shut down too quickly for me to note what it was...

Comment: @user20358 - You probably need to install it as admin.

Comment: installed it. Trying to find the appropriate template for generating DTOs without any luck! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

Found nothing suitable so created a very simple TSQL script. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/evgeny-myasishchev/8711676).

Sample output:

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string ExternalId { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }
        public bool IsBuiltIn { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public bool IsAuthorizedOnAllDepartments { get; set; }
}
```